# How to trigger a function in jquery

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am using a textbox for getting username and password.

Once user enters his/her name in name text box password textbox wants to display. While form is submitted and when user clicks on name text box drop down values of user name from cookies all displayed so when user selects username from displayed drop down i dont know how to make password textbox to appear.

i had used `autocomplete` to avoid displayin cookies but doesnt works for me

```
Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name" autocomplete="off"><br />
Pwd:  <input type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd" style="display: none;">
```

Jquery function i had used

```
$("input#name").bind("change keyup focus", function(){
$("input#pwd").show();
});
```

**Question** Cookies of the browser stores the usernames and password. so once user click on `name` textbox. list of username displayed in dropdown once user select a name then the written bind function not triggers.

How to solve this problem.

Comment: Just show the password field always. It's much simplier and more user friendly

Comment: I dont know why the bind func not triggers when value selected from cookies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `paste` Event like this,

```
$("input#name").bind("change keyup focus paste", function(){
   $("input#pwd").show();
});
```